# How do I react when a girl says she is wearing something and wants you to look but you don't want to be weird

Tags: awkward-situations

This may just be me being awkward, but me and this girl were shooting a green screen clip for a project, and I asked her jokingly, "hope your not wearing green", and we laughed. And she laughed some more and said that she was, and you could tell that she wanted me to look (I kinda like her and she kinda likes me) but how do I look and see without being awkward or her thinking I'm a perve. The green was on her shirt across her breasts and I thought it would be weird to look. What do I do? P. S. I'm not that great around girls.

Comment: What do you mean by "be weird"?  Seen as a creep?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

There's a difference between looking and staring.  The first is generally OK, the second is not.

First of all, I'd be careful about assuming a girl wants you to look.  In today's climate, you can be accused of all kinds of things.

Now that that's out of the way: look at the shirt for a second or two.  Don't comment on what's underneath.  She wanted you to look at the green on her shirt, so it's most likely OK to take a glance and comment that "Luckily that's not the same shade of green as our greenscreen, so we should be OK" or "hmmm... that might be the same shade as our greenscreen.  It'll be interesting to see what happens"  That would generally be considered acceptable.

Now, if you were to stare at her chest or comment on that, that would be unacceptable.  Different women have different standards about looking at their bodies and different tolerances for commenting on that, so play it safe there and don't go down that path.  (After all, we're all unique with different tastes and standards.)

Comment: Thank you. I get it now.